# sqlite, if the result of the calculation is negative, replace the value in the base with zero

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite3 table for discord.js with two id columns and dots. I need to set the value of the points to 0 every time they become negative. For example, if a user has 300 points, and someone took 400 points, it turns out -100. It should be replaced by 0.

I need something like this:
`update table set value = case when points < ? then 0 else points - ? end`

How i can did it?

| id | points |
| --- | --- |
| 123670 | 0 |
| 123987 | -300 |

Answer (score 0):

The following statement would achieve this goal for all records

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET  points = 0
WHERE points < 0
```

However this would be better if your application checked whether the value would become negative after subtracting the points or use the following approach that performs a check within the update. See working fiddle below showing how it assigns `0` when substracting `400` and the result of such would be negative:

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `points` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`id`, `points`)
VALUES
  ('123670', '0'),
  ('123987', '100');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE my_table
SET points = CASE 
                 WHEN points - 400 < 0 THEN 0
                 ELSE points - 400
             END
WHERE
    id=123987;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

| id | points |
| --- | --- |
| 123670 | 0 |
| 123987 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kQUcAnNQMdV4nuowUxnu12/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First update the table, so that there are not any negative `points`:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET points = 0
WHERE points < 0;
```

Then create a trigger that will update `points` to `0` every time its value is being set to negative:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_after_update_tab AFTER UPDATE ON tablename
WHEN NEW.points < 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE tablename
   SET points = 0
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b9b80e49697a8867fd41ecfa7627a6bc).

Also, you could have a `CHECK` constraint in the table to prevent insertions of negative `points`:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INTEGER, 
  points INTEGER, 
  CHECK(points >= 0)
);
```